# System of equations with absolute values of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The question asks to find all complex numbers a, such that this system of equations has exactly one solution: $|z - 4| = 2 |z - 1|, |z - a| + |z - 2a| = |a|$

It also asks to graphically represent the set of corresponding values of a.

For the first equation, I rewrote the complex number z = x + iy and used the fact that $|z| = \sqrt(x^2+y^2)$. At the end I got the expression $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, meaning that this first equation should represent a circle with the center (0,0) and radius 2.

So for the system to have one solution, corresponding graph for the second equation should only intersect with the circle in one point. We see that te second equation should represent an elipse with focus points being $a$ and $2a$. I'm not sure though how to find all numbers a so that this would be true. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the 2nd equation, think about the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve it by figuring out z has to be on a line between a and 2a.

Comment: You could write up what you have found, and post it as an answer.